# Is 'it' what is called data distribution modelling?

Tags: distributions, modeling

I have that histogram looking like this:

[image]

I need to have a distribution density of a known form like normal. Unfortunately and sadly, my data is not normal. I got a skewness here. So I had to deal with it and here's what I've done.

What I did was to take a look at a list of closed-form distributions available at Wikipedia and chose those ones, which fitted best. I chose lognormal distribution.

The next step was to figure out the parameters. Multiple times I plotted the density of the data in R via `plot(density(mydata))` and overlaid a lognormal density lines with possible parameters of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. By trial-and-error I found mu=0.6 and variance = 0.35. Finally I saw this below:

[image]

Looks nice! As being used to some tests I performed Anderson-Darling test and it's results are here:

```
> > ad.test(mydata, plnorm,0.6,0.35)
> 
>   Anderson-Darling GoF Test
> 
> data:  mydata  and  plnorm AD = 4.1954, p-value = 0.007006 alternative
> hypothesis: NA
```

Not so nice - p-value is below 0.05 threshold, but maybe it's because my data is 896 items. Maybe because of a little 'speed bump' on the right arm of the density.   But my question is:

**[Q]**: Is the procedure described above a way of finding a closed-form distribution for data? Or is it something different or I missed any point?

Comment: Conventional terminology: That thing you're labelling a histogram looks more like a kernel density estimate. [Compare the two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#/media/File:Comparison_of_1D_histogram_and_KDE.png) (from the wikipedia article on [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation))

Comment: What is the purpose of finding a simple density that fits your data? What can you do with it that you couldn't do with either the sample itself (e.g. if you need to estimate some quantile) or the KDE you computed?

Comment: @Glen_b I need to confirm that some psychological quality has such a distribution that its formula is easily written on the blackboard :-) like 'intelligence has a normal distribution'.

Comment: 1. Such statements will never be true unless you deliberately construct your measures to make them true (and even then it's generally not actually true -- intelligence is clearly not truly normally distributed, for example, even though with the usual measures it's deliberately designed to be).  You may be able to say something like "is approximately lognormal" (such statements are useful if we don't let ourselves be overly constrained by them) but there will be any number of other distributions you could also say it's approximately distributed as (none of which it will actually be). ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  2. In general you can't *confirm* a particular distribution is actually the case -- with a sufficient sample size you may be able to disconfirm it (i.e. to show it's simply not consistent with a sample from the relevant population).